# Cloud Run, how to get CSR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I`m getting SSL from comdodo

and It requires CSR (Certificate Signing Request)

> Simply paste your CSR in the form below. You may need to contact your webmaster/IT department/web host to obtain your CSR or read our CSR generating instructions for more details. Make sure to include the complete header and footer "BEGIN" and "END" lines exactly. Here is an example of what your CSR should look similar to. If you protect your CSR with a passphrase, please make sure to only include alpha-numeric characters, such as; A, B, C, 1, 2, 3, otherwise, you'll encounter an error. Also, do NOT use any International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) characters/symbols; such as, ñ, ú, ã, ë within the CSR as this will also create an error.

how do I get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your own TLS certificates (Google calls this "self-managed SSL") with Cloud Run, you'll need to provision (and pay for) a global external HTTPS load-balancer (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains?_ga=2.268382030.-116086138.1623860285#https-load-balancer)) this will entail [Creating a private key and cert](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#create-key-and-cert) which includes generating a CSR.

For some regions, you can use [Cloud Run domain mapping](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains?_ga=2.268382030.-116086138.1623860285#run) in which Google will provision a TLS certificate for you for your domain.

Comment: yah yah !!! that is what I have been looking for !! really thanks I need tls certificate to connect to another database server. I'm also using load balancing, using google domain and already done cloud run domain mapping. Could you please tell me where to download tls certificate.crt? in gcp console??

Comment: I don't understand. The links in my answer include an explanation for [creating a CSR](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#create-csr). If you want to download a certificate from a server, that's a different question but you can use openssl.

Comment: Ahh okay got it that was different question what I only can is create a CSR and not a .ctr file ! okay gotcha thanks !

Comment: @nounlace SSL certificates and SSL client certificates are different implementations of similar technology. To ensure you get the correct answer, provide details in your question. Database servers would not be using Comodo SSL certificates for client authorization.